# Docusign tag values are incorrectly getting applied to other tags

Tags: docusignapi

I have a use case where there a doc needs to get send from DS and via an API call and we are seeing some weirdness in DS around tagging. In all our templates, the tags for name and title get populated with the same text throughout the document. For example, if I write ‘Obama’ in one of the boxes next to “Name”, every single box in the document for name, title, and even company, gets populated with ‘Obama’.  Any ideas?

The DS documents are getting created via the API, and the tags are created like this:

```
    envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
    envelope.Tabs.Tab = new List<DocuSignAPI.Tab>();


    DocuSignAPI.Tab t = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    t.Type_x = 'Custom';
    DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab at = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    at.AnchorTabString = '\\n1\\';

    t.RecipientID =  recipient.ID;

    t.CustomTabRequired = false;


    at.IgnoreIfNotPresent  = true;
    t.AnchorTabItem = at;
    envelope.Tabs.Tab.add(t);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have set `same dataLabel` for all your DS Tags. If you have same datalabel for multiple DS Tags then DocuSign will replicate the same value for all DS Tags.

Comment: to be clear, i'm saying that both the company and name tags are getting set to the same value... I am ok with all the company tags getting set to A and the name tags set to B....

Comment: Are you sending it to the signer who has DocuSign Account, and he has same value in his Name and Company under My Preferences.

Comment: oh man..... that's an edge case! So, the signers aren't authenticating, so I don't think that's  the case.

Comment: Can you capture API logs following steps as explained in [DS API Logs](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging), I need to see how you are creating envelopes